# Two SFTP instances on one server

Tags: debian, sftp

I have a server where I need to import external data from two different locations. One sends the data automatically and the other is fed by different users.

I would like the users uploading data not to be able to see the data sent automatically.

So I thought about creating two SFTP instances on my main server (each one attached to a specific user).

What I would like to know is if this is possible or not?

And if it is, how do I configure /etc/ssh/sshd_config to declare two users and the two SFTP slots allocated to them?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you say you need two SFTP _servers_?

Comment: correct, "instances" is more appropriate

Comment: Or just two users on the same _server_ and _instance_ with different home directories and chrooting them in there?

Comment: Ok but I don't know how to do this.
If you could point me in the right direction, it would be nice.

Comment: Well yes, what I was trying to ask is "why do you think you need two separate instances?" What you're writing in the post doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. If it's the same folder, all instances will see the same files in that folder anyway... and if the users are accessing different folders, they can already do that with a single instance.

Comment: Please be mindful of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem. Your search terms should be "sftp chroot linux".

Comment: Ok I do my best to explain my problem by trying to master Shakespeare's language.
Well a priori my level in computer science is not high enough for me to find the right vocabulary. In my request, I had the idea of a lead but maybe it's not the right one.
You talk to me about chroot but it's a term I've heard about but I don't know its purpose. So it would seem that I have to look in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
# Creation of the SFTP directory
sudo mkdir -p /var/sftp
sudo chown root:root /var/sftp
sudo chmod 751 /var/sftp

# Creation of the user
sudo useradd --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin --groups sftp --home /var/sftp/user1 user1

sudo useradd --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin --groups sftp --home /var/sftp/user2 user2

# Creation of the folders
sudo mkdir -p /var/sftp/{user1,user2}

sudo chown root:sftp /var/sftp/user1
sudo chmod 751 /var/sftp/user1
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/user1/files
sudo chown user1:sftp /var/sftp/user1/files
sudo chmod 751 /var/sftp/user1/files

sudo chown root:sftp /var/sftp/user2
sudo chmod 751 /var/sftp/user2
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/user2/files
sudo chown user2:sftp /var/sftp/user2/files
sudo chmod 751 /var/sftp/user2/files

# Server setup
echo -e "\nMatch group sftp" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "\tChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "\tAllowTcpForwarding no" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "\tX11Forwarding no" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo -e "\tForceCommand internal-sftp" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo systemctl reload ssh

# Password creation
echo "user1:password" | sudo chpasswd
echo "user2:password" | sudo chpasswd
```